# Websocket Error: Error during WebSocket handshake: No response code found in status line

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I want to make a tcp connection to my server.
But i get en error everytime...

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://my.ip:1337/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: No response code found in status line: Echo server

Client:

```
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://my.ip:1337'); 
 connection.onopen = function () {
 connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
 };
```

Server:

```
   var net = require('net');
   var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
   socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
   socket.pipe(socket);
   console.log('request');
   });
   server.listen(1337, 'my.ip');
```

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`net.createServer` creates a *plain TCP server*, not a *websocket server*. Websockets use a specific protocol over TCP, which a plain TCP server does not follow. The browser successfully makes a network-level connect over TCP, but it then expects a websocket handshake to immediately follow, which the plain TCP server does not know how to provide.

To have your Node.js server listen for websocket connections, use the [`ws` module](http://einaros.github.io/ws/):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 1337});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        ws.send('this is an echo response; you just said: ' + message);
    });
    ws.send('send this message on connect');
});
```